# Movement of character animation in java libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

currently I am faced with a difficulty that my character animation doesn't seem to be fluid as when I move left or right my codes seems to be rushing through the movement of the left and right animations

```
public Mario(World world, PlayScreen screen, int score, int lives){
        super(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("Pink_Monster"));
        this.world = world;
        currentState = State.STANDING;
        previousState = State.STANDING;
        stateTimer = 0;
        movingRight = true;

        Array<TextureRegion> frames = new Array<TextureRegion>();

//For moving left and right animations
        for (int i = 8; i < 13; i++)
            frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), i * 32, 0, 37, 40));
        PlayerRun = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.1f,frames);
        frames.clear();
//For jumping animations
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), i * 32, 0, 37, 40));
        PlayerJump = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.1f, frames);

        PlayerStand = new TextureRegion(getTexture(), 583, 1, 40, 40);

        controls = new Controls();
```

Can't seem to figure out why my jumping animation is fine no issues with that but when it moving left and right the character seems to be glitching through the sprite images that I have like lagging of sorts

This is the png I used for my character:
[image: png for character]

Comment: The code seems to be ok to me. Maybe there is a problem with the texture. Are you sure, that every frame is exactly 37px in with?

Comment: I mean technically all of the png that i uploaded is thru texturepacker sooo they are spaced out evenly with one another but i assumed that if my jump animation worked out smoothly by right there shouldn't be any issues with the running animation

Comment: The issue might be with the delta time being calculated. I recently had a similar issue, where the animation (when moving the character left and right) was smooth at first, but quickly gained speed and was moving from one corner to the other, and it seemed to be because we were accumulating the delta time instead of resetting it after every animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your image with gimp and configure the grid to be 32x40 pixels (the area that you crop) you can see that the images are not placed correctly:

[image]

If you created this image with a texture packing tool, there should be a **.atlas** file (or something similar, depending on which tool you used) that contains the correct positioning information. If you use the atlas to load the animation, you don't need to find the texture regions yourself. That makes it much easier to find the correct textures.

Comment: Although the weird thing is only when moving left to right is affected the rest for jumping and idle is fine, as for the .atlas file .pack is alright too right? Yea i used texturepacker to generate the .pack file